# ERROR MapRZKRMFinderUtils: Unable to determine ResourceManager service address from Zookeeper

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am getting the error below while trying to create a DataFrame from a csv file using the below command:

```scala
val auctionDataFrame=spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("inferSchema",true)
  .load("/apps/auctiondata.csv")
  .toDF("auctionid","bid","bidtime","bidder","bidderrate","openbid","price","item","daystolive")`
```

```
20/05/06 15:27:14 WARN ZKDataRetrieval: Can not get children of /services/resourcemanager/master with error: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /services/resourcemanager/master
20/05/06 15:27:14 ERROR MapRZKRMFinderUtils: Unable to determine ResourceManager service address from Zookeeper at node1:5181,node2:5181,node3:5181
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to determine ResourceManager service address from Zookeeper at node1:5181,node2:5181,node3:5181
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.MapRZKRMFinderUtils.mapRZkBasedRMFinder(MapRZKRMFinderUtils.java:121)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.MapRZKBasedRMAddressFinder.getRMAddress(MapRZKBasedRMAddressFinder.java:43)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.HAUtil.getCurrentRMAddress(HAUtil.java:72)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Master.getMasterAddress(Master.java:60)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Master.getMasterPrincipal(Master.java:74)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:114)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:206)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:317)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:206)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1333)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1327)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1368)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1367)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.findFirstLine(CSVFileFormat.scala:206)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:60)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:183)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:135)
  ... 48 elided
```

I run spark-shell using : /opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/bin/spark-shell

Could you please help me how to fix this error. 
Thanks

Abir

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue when my spark streaming application was compiled against older version of MapR and dependencies.

But when I re submitted the Spark app by replacing some of the dependencies by version "up to date" yarn executed it

Make sure you compile time jar's version and the runtime jars are same.
That includes Spark 2.1.0,hadoop jars

Comment: I didn't understand well. Can you explain a little bit more.??!